# CFT with noncompact target space => no well-defined vacuum state?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, branes

In [Maldacena & Nunez's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007018), on page 6, when they discuss the compactification of Type-IIB on $\textbf{R}^6 \times K3$ (with D3 branes wrapped on $\textbf{R}^{1,1} \times \Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is a Riemann surface inside K3), they take the following two limits in this order:

(1) $\alpha' \rightarrow 0$ with the size of $\Sigma$ and K3 fixed.

(2) $E << 1/\text{size}(\Sigma)$, i.e. a low energy limit in which we restrict to energies less than the (inverse) size of the Riemann surface.

The claim made is that when these limits are taken in this order, the CFT that lives on the worldvolume of the stack of D3 branes has a non-compact target space. If the CFT is the worldvolume theory, then (like in the bosonic string or RNS string) the target space should be the transverse space, which is already non-compact to begin with. So why is it that this limit is being attributed as giving rise to the non-compactness?

It is also said that a non-compact target space implies that the CFT does not have a well-defined vacuum state. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of compact vs non-compact target spaces can be studied in the case of free bosons. There the energy is $E\sim p^2$ where $p$ is the momentum.

If your boson is compact, i.e. the target space is a circle, then $p$ is quantized and there is a gap above the ground state $E=0$. (Actually you also have winding states but they do not change the picture.) The spectrum is discrete, and you can normalize the states such that their norms are one.

If the boson is non-compact, i.e. the target space is the real line, then $p$ can take very small values and there is a continuum above the ground state. In particular, scalar products of states are given by a delta function $\langle p|p'\rangle = \delta(p-p')$, so the norm of any given state, including the ground state, is technically infinite.

This might be why the ground state is not considered as a "well-defined vacuum state".

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Sylvain Ribault. Just to clarify, what is the target space in this case?

Comment: @leastaction: Modified the post in order to specify target spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Sylvain Ribault. I meant to ask what is the target space for Maldacena & Nunez? They claim that due to the specific order of limits, the brane explores only a neighborhood of the Riemann surface and the other directions are non-compact. This is a bit confusing to me, because there is a 2d CFT (in the IR limit, compactified from 4d) whose target space is purportedly being referred to: the transverse space has non-compact directions before and after this limit.[On an unrelated sidenote, thank you for your online notes on CFT. I found them very useful!]

Comment: @leastaction: Oops, I misunderstood your question about the target space. As far as I understand, the idea of Maldacena and Nunez is that for an observer (or string) that is confined very close to a point of some space, that space appears flat and therefore noncompact. Their case is a bit more complicated: instead of a point you have a Riemann surface submanifold $M\subset K3$. Their limit might amount to replacing $K3$ with $M\times \mathbb{C}$, or maybe some fibration of $\mathbb{C}$ over $M$.

Comment: Thanks @Sylvain Ribault. That makes sense. Thanks again for your answer and comment.